# React Native + Redux: Why does Switch immediately turns back to false after being switched to true?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reactjs

In iOS React Native + Redux, I am using the following Switch component (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html). It is first set as off, but then when switched on, it immediately switches off by itself. What may be the issue?

This is my set up:

```
<Switch
  onValueChange={this._handleSwitch}
  value={switch.currentValue}
/>
```

And the action triggered is:

```
  _handleSwitch(value) {
    this.props.actions.triggerSwitch(value)
  }
```

And the action is:

```
export function triggerSwitch(value) {
  return {
    type: TRIGGER_SWITCH,
    currentValue: value
  }
}
```

And in the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  currentValue: false
}

function switchReducer(switch = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TRIGGER_SWITCH:
      return {
        currentValue: action.currentValue
      }

     default:
       return switch
  }
}

export default switchReducer
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try to check your default case, seems like its called after `TRIGGER_SWITCH`

Comment: use `_handleSwitch = (value) => {  this.props.actions.triggerSwitch(value)}`

Comment: @Maxx Could it be that my redux is set up incorrectly? Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235637/react-native-why-isnt-redux-correctly-updating-the-state

Answer (score 5):

It is not because of redux, for `Switch` to work, we need to explicitly set the `value` from a state, otherwise it is set back to `false` immediately

```
<Switch
  value={this.state.hasRead}
  onValueChange={(value) => {
    this.setState({
      hasRead: value
    })
}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the described problem with redux and Switch, but the only issue I had is that switch is a reserved word, so I changed it to switchState. In case someone needs the working example:

***js/actions/actionTypes.js***

```
export const TRIGGER_SWITCH = 'TRIGGER_SWITCH';
```

---

***js/actions/switchActions.js***

```
import { TRIGGER_SWITCH } from './actionTypes';

export const triggerSwitch = value => ({
  type: TRIGGER_SWITCH,
  currentValue: value
});
```

---

***js/reducers/switchReducer.js***

```
import { TRIGGER_SWITCH } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  currentValue: false
};

const switchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TRIGGER_SWITCH:
      return {
        currentValue: action.currentValue
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default switchReducer;
```

---

***js/store.js***

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  combineReducers
} from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import switchReducer from './reducers/switchReducer';

const logger = createLogger();

export default (initialState = {}) => (
  createStore(
    combineReducers({
      switchState: switchReducer
    }),
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(logger)
  )
);
```

---

***js/components/App.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Switch
} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._handleSwitch = this._handleSwitch.bind(this);
  }

  _handleSwitch(value) {
    this.props.actions.triggerSwitch(value);
  }

  render() {
    const { switchState } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this._handleSwitch}
          value={switchState.currentValue}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

---

***js/containers/App.js***

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { triggerSwitch } from '../actions/switchActions';
import App from '../components/App';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  switchState: state.switchState
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    triggerSwitch
  }, dispatch)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

---

***index.ios.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createStore from './js/store';
import App from './js/containers/App';

const store = createStore();


const SwitchTest = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SwitchTest', () => SwitchTest);

export default SwitchTest;
```

---

***package.json dependencies***

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly bind your `_handleSwitch` function? Does `this.props.actions.triggerSwitch(value)` dispatch okay?

Use a [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger) to examine your state and actions at every stage and make sure your component receives the correct value after a switch.

Comment: Yes, in the constructor, and I do have redux-logger running and shows that prev and next state correctly. But when I trigger it, it goes back to `false` by itself.

Comment: Could it be that my redux is set up incorrectly? Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235637/react-native-why-isnt-redux-correctly-updating-the-state

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing react with ES6 components styles such as `class Blah extends React` you need to use `.bind(this)` to change run-time scope.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this._handleSwitch = this._handleSwitch.bind(this);
}
```

this might work. or follow @stereodenis 's comment. That does same but every time your component's re-rendered, it'll create method.

Comment: I'm aware and already defined it as such but still doesn't work.

Comment: Could it be that my redux is set up incorrectly? Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235637/react-native-why-isnt-redux-correctly-updating-the-state

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. My switch components were in a FlatList. Though render() method was called, switch value never got update. As a result, it reverted back to old value.

In order to resolve, FlatList needed a way to know that it needs to re-render the list. `extraData` was used for this purpose.

For details, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505891/437146).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Switch
  onValueChange={this._handleSwitch}
  value={(switch.currentValue) ? true : false}
/>
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an Android specific issue; it works fine on iOS without this modification. It is necessary to interrupt the default event propagation and handle it manually. Here's an example using hooks where the logic for the switch is handled elsewhere. You could also handle it locally with

`[value, setValue] = useState()`

and then use `setValue` as your `handler`.

```
const Row = ({ onOff, handler, label }) => {
const onSwitchChange = evt => {
  handler(evt.nativeEvent.value);
  // Interrupt the default event and handle it manually
  // Only necessary on Android but it also works on iOS so no branching necessary
  evt.stopPropagation();
};

return (
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <View style={styles.label}>
      <Text style={styles.labelText}>{label}</Text>
    </View>
    <Switch
      style={styles.switchSize}
      value={onOff}
      onChangeCapture={onSwitchChange}
    />
  </View>
);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered a similar issue (not related to redux). For me the switch is changing back immediately when the switch is placed in a ListView and the ListView's dataSource is not updated in Switch's onValueChange.
Demo: https://rnplay.org/apps/tb6-fw
Fixed: https://rnplay.org/apps/FfoVmg

The links are not working anymore, so here is the code for Switch in ListView not working properly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  Switch
} from 'react-native';


export default class SwitchTest extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    this.state = {
      switch1Value: false,
      switch2Value: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([{ data: 'some row data...'}]),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Switch
          value={this.state.switch1Value}
          onValueChange={value => this.setState({ switch1Value: value })}
        />
        <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData) => (
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text>{rowData.data}</Text>
                <Switch
                  value={this.state.switch2Value}
                  onValueChange={value => this.setState({ switch2Value: value })}
                />
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  listWrapper: {
    height: 100,
    padding: 10
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SwitchTest', () => SwitchTest);
```

The fix is to move switch2Value state inside dataSource and update dataSource inside Switch's onValueChange.

```
// ...

this.state = {
  switch1Value: false,
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([{ data: 'some row data...', switch2Value: false }]),
};

// ...

        renderRow={(rowData) => (
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text>{rowData.data}</Text>
            <Switch
              value={rowData.switch2Value}
              onValueChange={value => this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([{ ...rowData, switch2Value: value }])
              })}
            />
          </View>
        )}

// ...
```

Comment: Hey, links are not working anymore. Maybe a snippet within the message would be better for next time :)

Comment: @NicGutierrez, Sorry for that, I've added code to my answer.