# React Native: Why isn't redux correctly updating the state?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reactjs

In Redux + iOS React Native, the updated state logs properly in the parent component, but when logged inside another method, it just logs the initialState.

I have the following components that call the actions:

```
  _handleFirstName(text) {
    this.props.actions.updateFirstName(text)
  }

  _handleLastName(text) {
    this.props.actions.updateLastName(text)
  }

  <TextInput
    placeholder='Enter First Name'
    onChangeText={this._handleFirstName.bind(this)}
    value={this.props.userInfo.firstName}
  />

  <TextInput
    placeholder='Enter Last Name'
    onChangeText={this._handleLastName.bind(this)}
    value={this.props.userInfo.lastName}
  />
```

And my actions are set up like so:

```
export function updateFirstName(text) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_FIRST_NAME,
    firstName: text
  }
}

export function updateLastName(text) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_LAST_NAME,
    lastName: text
  }
}
```

And for my reducers:

```
const initialState = {
    newUser: false,
    active: false,
}

function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UPDATE_FIRST_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        firstName: action.firstName
      }

    case UPDATE_LAST_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        lastName: action.lastName
      }

     default:
       return state
  }
}

export default userReducer
```

And the state correctly updates the properties and returns a `userInfo` state. But then when I console log the updated `userInfo` inside another method, rather retrieving the updated state, it just logs the `userInfo` initialState of:

```
const initialState = {
    newUser: false,
    active: false,
}
```

And the attempt to log it is done like so:

```
  _logUserInfo() {
    console.log(this.props.userInfo)
  }

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._logUserInfo.bind(this)}>
  <Text>Log User Info</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Even though it correctly console logs the updated state in the parent component, why is it just logging the initialState instead of the updated state when called inside another method?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

This is how state is connected to components, in `NavigationRootContainer.js`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import NavigationRoot from '../Components/NavigationRoot'
import { updateFirstName, updateLastName, } from '../Actions/userActions'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    userInfo: state.userReducer,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    updateFirstName: (value) => updateFirstName(value),
    updateLastName: (value) => updateLastName(value),
  }
)(NavigationRoot)
```

In `index.ios.js`:

```
import NavigationRootContainer from './src/Containers/NavigationRootContainer'


const userProject = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationRootContainer/>
  </Provider>
)
```

And the props are passed down like so with root component `NavigationRoot.js` using `<NavigationCardStack/>`:

```
  _renderScene (props) {
    return (
      <route.component{...route.passProps} actions={this.props}/>
    )
  }

    <NavigationCardStack
      direction='horizontal'
      navigationState={this.props.navigation}
      onNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)}
      renderScene={this._renderScene}
      renderOverlay={this.renderOverlay}
      style={styles.container}
    />
```

Comment: Hi there! In the component with _logUserInfo, can you show either how you connect it to Redux using `connect` or the component hierarchy that passes your userReducer to it via props?

Comment: How do you define `this.props.actions`?

Comment: Can you put all code of the first component?

Comment: @grales Sure thing! Updated the original post

Comment: @TimoSta It is passed down from the root component via `actions={this.props}`. Updated the original post. Please take a look

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo Yes, I updated the original post.

Comment: @grales just checking to see if you saw my previous comment. please let me know.

Comment: @TimoSta please let me know if you saw my previous comment. I really need guidance on this

Comment: @SebastianLorenzo Did you get a chance to take a look at the update?

Comment: Do you correctly import your `store` in your `index.ios.js`? What happens if you console.log it, doest it get updated as it should? It is hard to debug without a complete overview... You should consider setting up a rnplay.org example or event a public git repo.

Comment: @damusnet Here are the details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279531/react-native-redux-how-to-pass-down-updated-state-to-child-components-every-tim/39279574#39279574

Comment: Aren't both arguments passed to `connect` supposed to be functions, not a function and an object, as in `NavigationRootContainer`'s `connect`?