# How to re-render flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Unlike ListView we can update this.state.datasource. Is there any method or example to update FlatList or re-render it?

My goal is to update the text value when user press button ...

```
renderEntries({ item, index }) {
    return(
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.setState({value: this.state.data[index].value+1})>
             <Text>{this.state.data[index].value}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}

<FlatList 
    ref={(ref) => { this.list = ref; }} 
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.entry.entryId} 
    data={this.state.data} 
    renderItem={this.renderEntries.bind(this)} 
    horizontal={false} />
```

Comment: The [docs for FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) say "This is a `PureComponent` which means that it will not re-render if props remain shallow- equal. Make sure that everything your `renderItem` function depends on is passed as a prop that is not `===` after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the `data` prop and parent component state." Are you following this advice?

Comment: No matter what I tried with `extraData` and `shouldItemUpdate`, I could not get the list to re-render. What I ended up doing was clearing out the state, waiting for that to render and then updating the state. `this.setState({ data: null }, () => { this.setState({ data: actualData }) });`

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Use the `extraData` property on your FlatList component.

As the documentation states:

> By passing `extraData={this.state}` to `FlatList` we make sure `FlatList` will re-render itself when the `state.selected` changes. Without setting this prop, `FlatList` would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a `PureComponent` and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

Comment: I am using redux and in that case sending data like `data={this.props.searchBookResults}` and neither `extraData={this.state}` nor `extraData={this.props}` is working for me. And `data={this.props.searchBookResults}` is not working too. What to do ?

Comment: @EdwinVargas did you find any solution? I couldn't

Comment: Use extraData: to refresh your <FlatList>
`...
data={this.props.searchBookResults}
extraData={this.state.refresh}
onPress={()={this.setState({ refresh: !refresh})}`

Comment: @Sujit,@EdwinVargas did you got any solution?

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem. It doesn't matter what I pass on `extraData`, the component does not update :(

Comment: passing `this.state` as `extradata` is kind of bad practice though. Use `this.state.datasource`

Comment: @DenisCappelini, make sure data passed into the `extraData` prop changes when child item[s] must re-render. For example, if list items can be active/inactive, make sure that status variable, whether part of the `this.state` object or `this.props` object is what should go inside `extraData`. It might be a cursor, or an array of active items, etc.

Comment: @Sujit I was running into the same issue but then I realized that I had implemented the `shouldComponentUpdate()`, once I updated that or completely comment out, things were working just as described in the documentation.

Comment: For me list didn't rerender when data array was sorted another way - so items remained same and only their order was changed. Adding extraData did the trick.

Comment: How to update a single item in flatlist without re-rendering all flatlist items?

Comment: @praj, found any solution for redux?

Comment: hello, Guys, I want to re-render Flatlist after deleting the last item, can check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780167/i-cant-re-render-the-flatlist-after-empty-data

Answer (score 69):

For quick and simple solution Try:

1. set extra data to a boolean value.

   extraData={this.state.refresh}
2. Toggle the value of boolean state when you want to re-render/refresh list

   ```
   this.setState({ 
       refresh: !this.state.refresh
   })
   ```

Comment: That's exactly what I need since I'll be adding data to the data prop. Also, that is a super weird implementation by the React-Native team... it'd make way more sense to have a refresh function or property on data. IE: `this.data.refresh()`. Instead, we set a boolean and change it. The booleans value itself has no meaning, so what is the point in it existing?... (There is no point, other than making the data refresh right?)

Comment: @HradeshKumar I do it but the last item inside Data it's can't disappear !

Comment: this works like charm, but I still don't know why `this.state.users` wasn't working, even though I was changing a flag in some users.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, can you please help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547030/flatlist-does-not-rerender-even-if-state-assigned-to-extradata-changes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the only problem here with me is that i want to get the state of another class. There is another class where there is a button and after clicking that button, i am also changing the state of that component. Now i want to send that state to its parent component where the flatList is actually rendering. Please show if you have answer

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 22):

Oh that's easy, just use `extraData`

You see the way extra data works behind the scenes is the **FlatList** or the **VirtualisedList** just checks [wether that object has changed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/63f990121ad5f58dfd07ccfed2bb640b08164f73/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L466) via a normal `onComponentWillReceiveProps` method.

So all you have to do is make sure you give something that changes to the `extraData`.

Here's what I do:

I'm using [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) so all I do is I pass a Map (immutable object) that contains whatever I want to watch.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.calendarMonths}
    extraData={Map({
        foo: this.props.foo,
        bar: this.props.bar
    })}
    renderItem={({ item })=>((
        <CustomComponentRow
            item={item}
            foo={this.props.foo}
            bar={this.props.bar}
        />
    ))}
/>
```

In that way, when `this.props.foo` or `this.props.bar` change, our `CustomComponentRow` will update, because the immutable object will be a different one than the previous.

Comment: i finally understood `extraData`! thanks for the link to the `VirtualisedList` code!

Comment: hello,@SudoPiz I want to re-render Flatlist after deleting the last item, can check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780167/i-cant-re-render-the-flatlist-after-empty-data

Answer (score 9):

OK.I just found out that if we want the FlatList to know the data change outside of the data prop,we need set it to extraData, so I do it like this now:

```
<FlatList data={...} extraData={this.state} .../>
```

refer to : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata

Comment: The best implementation... I preferred to set it as the same as the data prop, so it doesn't refresh when anything in the state changes, but this is the EASIEST implementation by far. Thanks!

Comment: hello, @MahdiBashirpour
 I want to re-render Flatlist after deleting the last item, can check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780167/i-cant-re-render-the-flatlist-after-empty-data

Answer (score 5):

after lots of searching and looking for real answer finally i got the answer which i think it is the best :

```
       <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
      onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={1}
      extraData={this.state.data}
      removeClippedSubviews={true}
      **keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index }**
              />
    .....
```

my main problem was (KeyExtractor) 
i was not using it like this .
not working : keyExtractor={ (item) => item.ID}
after i changed to this it worked like charm
i hope this helps someone.

Comment: can you put the value of `this.state.refreshing` and function `handleRefresh`?

Answer (score 5):

Just an extension on the previous answers here.
Two parts to ensure, Make sure that you add in extraData and that your keyExtractor is unique. If your keyExtractor is constant a rerender will not be triggered.

```
<FlatList
data={this.state.AllArray}
extraData={this.state.refresh}
renderItem={({ item,index })=>this.renderPhoto(item,index)}
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
>
                                    </FlatList>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to have a Button, you can update the data with a setState inside the onPress. SetState will then re-render your FlatList.

Comment: there is a setState in my touchablehighlight. the setState is working fine but the flatlist is not showing update of the state value -> this.state.value

Comment: The values in your FlastList isn't updating because you aren't updating the data source directly. this.state.data is what is rendered with the FlatList, but in the onPress you are only updating this.state.value.

Comment: sorry my mistake, question typo. should be this.state.data[index].value

Answer (score 2):

```
const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = setState(null);
....
const FlatListItem = (item) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setItemSelected(item.id)}>
            <View style={ (itemSelected === item.id) ? style.itemWrapperActive : style.itemWrapper }>
                <Text>{ item.label }</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
....
<FlatList
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ width: 20 }} />}
    data={ flatListData }
    renderItem={ ({item}) => FlatListItem(item) }
    keyExtractor={ (item) => item.id }
    extraData={ itemSelected }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding `extraData={this.state}` Please check code below for more detail

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.arr}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, to force a re-render, just change the variable `machine`

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(machine)

useEffect(() => {
    setSelected(machine)
}, [machine])
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above solutions. None of them works. In the end I had two choice

1. Try Section List
2. Clean my state data by calling `setState(undefined)` and then set data again by calling `setState(value)`. This will re-render the whole list.

I tried the second one and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For latest **React Native** as of this writing--though I think this might also be true for older versions, syntax would be a bit different for set state for older versions:

- "@react-navigation/native": "^6.x.x",
- "react-native": "0.71.4"

Pushing an Item in the array does not trigger rendering because it is not changing the array in memory, for that you have to copy the array and update its state like so:

```
const initialItems = [
  {text: 'hi'},
  {text: 'hello'},
  {text: 'goodbye'},
];
const [items, setItems] = React.useState(initialItems);

const onClickInsert = () => {
  const copyItems = [...items]; // copy via spread operator, very important!
  // pushing an item reuses the same memory so it does not trigger render
  copyItems.push({text: 'greetings, lad!'});
  // setting the items' state using a copy will require
  // a new memory allocation thus triggering the render
  setItems(copyItems);
};

return (
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={items}
      renderItem={({item}) => (<Text>{item.text}</Text>)}
    />
    <Button
      title="insert"
      onPress={() => onClickInsert ()}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced `FlatList` with `SectionList` and it is updates properly on state change.

```
<SectionList
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.entry.entryId} 
  sections={section}
  renderItem={this.renderEntries.bind(this)}
  renderSectionHeader={() => null}
/>
```

The only thing need to keep in mind is that `section` have diff structure:

```
const section = [{
  id: 0,
  data: this.state.data,
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the trick was extraData and drilling down into the item component one more time

```
state = {
  uniqueValue: 0
}

<FlatList
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
  data={this.props.photos}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
/>

renderItem = (item) => {
  if(item.item.selected) {
    return ( <Button onPress={this.itemPressed.bind(this, item)}>Selected</Button> );
  }
  return ( <Button onPress={this.itemPressed.bind(this, item)}>Not selected</Button>);
}

itemPressed (item) {
  this.props.photos.map((img, i) => {
    if(i === item.index) {
      if(img['selected') {
        delete img.selected;
      } else {
        img['selected'] = true;
      }
      this.setState({ uniqueValue: this.state.uniqueValue +1 });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is extraData here ?

Answer (score 0):

Put variables that will be changed by your interaction at `extraData`

You can be creative.

For example if you are dealing with a changing list with checkboxes on them.

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.data.items}
      extraData={this.state.data.items.length * (this.state.data.done.length + 1) }
      renderItem={({item}) => <View>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want the FlatList to **know** the data change **both prop and state**,we can construct an object referencing both prop and state and refresh the flatlist.

```
const hasPropOrStateChange = { propKeyToWatch: this.props, ...this.state};
<FlatList data={...} extraData={this.hasPropOrStateChange} .../>
```

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata

Answer (score 0):

In react-native-flatlist, they are a property called as extraData. add the below line to your flatlist.

```
 <FlatList
          data={data }
          style={FlatListstyles}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using functional component, in that I am using Flatlist with redux data.
I am managing all the state with Redux store.
Here is the solution to update the Flatlist data after the api call.

I was first doing like this:-

```
const DATA  = useSelector((state) => state.address.address);


<FlatList
    style = {styles.myAddressList}
    data = {DATA}
    renderItem = {renderItem}
    keyExtractor = {item => item._id}
    ListEmptyComponent = {EmptyList}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={SeparatorWhite}
    extraData = {refresh}
    
    />
```

but the data was not re-rendering my Flatlist data at all.

As a solution I did like given Below:-

```
<FlatList
    style = {styles.myAddressList}
    data = {useSelector((state) => state.address.address)}
    renderItem = {renderItem}
    keyExtractor = {item => item._id}
    ListEmptyComponent = {EmptyList}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={SeparatorWhite}
    />
```

I am passing the Redux state directly to the Flatlist Datasource rather than allocating it to the variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For those using redux, I used `extraData` prop and added loading there what I also did was I created a custom hook called `usePrevious`

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

export const usePrevious = <T>(value: T): T | undefined => {
  const ref = useRef<T>();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
};
```

and used it like this on my Item.

```
const prevData = usePrevious({data});

//CODES...

useEffect(() => {
    if (prevData?.data === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    if (prevData?.data?.someID !== data?.someId) {
      // do something.
      showSubChildren(false)
    }
  }, [data?.AuctionName, prevData, resetItemStates]);
```

So what basically happened here was, your item will check if data is from `undefined` (first time). Then It will check if some data property has changed and if it has, you should do something.

Answer (score 0):

Doing like below will instantly make the flatlist item change reflected instantly. You can do this similarly in component also if you are not using redux.

```
  let list = Object.assign([], state.auctionList);
  let objIndex;
  //Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
  objIndex = list.findIndex(
    obj => obj.auction_vehicles.vehicle_id == payload.vehicle_id,
  );

  // //Update object's property.
  list[objIndex].auction_vehicles.time_left = payload.offer_expiry_time;
  list[objIndex].auction_vehicles.starting_price = payload.amount;
  list[objIndex].auction_vehicles.bidding_status =
    payload.highest_bidder_flag;

  return { ...state, auctionList: list };
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright fellow traveler, you may rest here. If `extraData` hasn't helped you, then your issue is with your `keyExtractor` prop.

I was writing a chat component and couldn't get my messages to rerender. The flow is pretty simple.

A source user would write a message and that would head over to my backend with:

```
{
    id: '<random-uuid>',
    read: false,
    received: false,
    sent: false,
    pending: true
}
```

It'd then get stored in the db and be returned as,

```
{
    id: '<new-id-from-db>',
    read: false,
    received: false,
    sent: true,
    pending: false
}
```

Assuming the target user is online, the message is then marked as either received or read, depending on whether or not the target user has the same chat open with the source user who just sent the message. Assuming they're in the same chat, the message object gets updated in the database like so:

```
{
    id: '<id-from-db>',
    read: true,
    received: true,
    sent: true,
    pending: false
}
```

Yeah, well, this all worked great and all on the backend, however my `FlatList` component only seemed to update on `sent: true`.

After some hair pulling, it quickly became obvious why. My `keyExtractor`:

```
const keyExtractor = (message) => message.id;
```

The reason it updated the first time (from `pending` to `sent`) was because once it returned from the backend the first time, it had a new `id` instead of the temporary uuid that I gave it.

Anyway, I managed to fix this by doing this:

```
const keyExtractor = (message) =>
    `${message.id}_${message.read}_${message.received}_${message.sent}_${message.pending}`;
```

For ulterior reasons beyond my control, there's no `updated_at` property. If you have one, and on every status change you update this `updated_at` field, then you may be able to get away with something like this:

```
const keyExtractor = (message) => message.updated_at;
```

Or if you prefer sticking to uuids (which have no actual effect on your data or models within the realm of `keyExtractor`), you could try something like this:

```
const randomUuid = () => {
    const randomInt = (min = 100000000, max) => {
        if (max == null) {
            max = min;
            min = 0;
        }

        return min + Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min));
    };

    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/x/g, () => randomInt(15).toString(16));
};

const keyExtractor = () => randomUuid();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
onRefresh={true}
```

inside your `flatList` component.

Comment: this creates an error, u need then to use `refreshing` prop

Answer (score -1):

Flatlist's extraData wasn't working for me and I happened to be using a prop from redux. This sounded similar to issues from the comments in ED209's answer. I ended up manually calling setState when I receive the prop.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: StateProps) {
    if (this.props.yourProp != null && nextProps.yourProp) {
        this.setState({ yourState: processProp(nextProps.yourProp) });
    }
}


<FlatList
  data={this.state.yourState}
  extraData={this.state.yourState}
/>
```

For those of you using > React 17 use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state)