# PureComponent FlatList not re-rendering even when using extraData={this.state}

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

After some research it seems I need to use a PureComponent rather than a regular Component to improve the speed of my FlatList. This way it will not re-render the entire list, just the row that was changed. However the flatlist does not re-render when I do it this way.

This question [How to re-render flatlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397803/how-to-re-render-flatlist) and others like it state I have to use `extradata={this.state}` in my `FlatList` so it can see if any data changes have occured in the data source but its not working

I have tried this.state, this.state.symbols, tried using a boolean and force changing it in my onPress function but nothing seems to be working.

I moved my list item out of the render function into its own class in an external js file

```
export default class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { item } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
                    <Ionicons style={styles.listItemIcon} name={item.iconName} />
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.listItem}>
                        {item.coinName.toUpperCase()} {item.symbol}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };
}
```

My renderListItem function now looks like this

```
renderListItem = ({ item , index}) => {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.onPressListItem(index)}
            >
            <MyListItem
            item={item}
            />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
```

This is the onPress function. As you can see the state is changed here so not sure why `extraData` doesnt see that

```
onPressListItem = ( index ) => {
        const copyOfSymbolsList = [...this.state.symbols];
        thePressedSymbol = copyOfSymbolsList[index];

        if (thePressedSymbol.iconName === 'md-star') {
            thePressedSymbol.iconName = 'md-star-outline';
        }else{
            thePressedSymbol.iconName = 'md-star';
        }
        copyOfSymbolsList[index] = thePressedSymbol;

        this.setState({ 
            symbols: copyOfSymbolsList
        });

    }
```

This is my FlatList

```
<FlatList
                    data={this.state.symbols}
                    extraData={this.state.symbols}
                    keyExtractor= {(item, index) => item.symbol}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderListSeparator}
                    renderItem={this.renderListItem}
                />
```

Comment: did you tried `forceUpdate()` ?

Comment: @zoonosis `PureComponent` only expects simple state ... for the comparison to work properly ...

Comment: If you are using lodash deep clone the array and try const copyOfSymbolsList = _.cloneDeep(this.state.symbols);

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli not sure what you mean by simple state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to manipulate the `thePressedSymbol` in your `onPressListItem` function like this

```js
onPressListItem = ( index ) => {
        const copyOfSymbolsList = [...this.state.symbols];
        thePressedSymbol = {
          ...copyOfSymbolsList[index],
          iconName: copyOfSymbolsList[index].iconName === 'md-star' ? 'md-star-outline' : 'md-star';
        }
        copyOfSymbolsList[index] = thePressedSymbol;

        this.setState({ 
            symbols: copyOfSymbolsList
        });

    }
```

This is because in `Javascript`, Object is a `reference` type. You can try this in the console

```js
var person1={
  name: 'John',
  age: 10
}
var person2 = person1;
console.log(person1===person2); // output: true
person2.age = 20;
console.log(person1===person2); // output: true
console.log(person1.age, person2.age); // output: 20 20

var person3 = {...person1};
console.log(person1===person3}; // output: false
```

Which means, in order to make the `FlatList` rerender, you need to either pass a whole new `symbol` item to replace the existing one in the array (which is what my solution above did); or (i haven't try this) you can also implement your own `FlatList` component to do a deep comparison instead of shallow comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much @wicky So basically, instead of changing just the iconName part of the json array, then entire contents of the row was re-written with the same data (except for the new iconName). Seems like a waste having to do all of them, but it works.

Comment: You're welcome. Yea, it might seems like a 'hack' to go around FlatList's shallow comparison. But IMO a better solution than having to implement your own deep comparison onto the FlatList ;)