# re-render flatlist when data changes in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a flatlist in a react-native app. This flatlist is filled with an array (renderItem). This works.

When I click on an item in the flatlist, the item should dissapear.

```
const [currentValues, setCurrentValues] = useState([])

// a fetch fills the currentValues-array with data from a 
// database here, this works

<FlatList
data={currentValues}
renderItem={(item, index) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteItem(item.id)} style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'black' }}>
            <Text>{item.username}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}} />
```

With the following function, I delete the item from the array:

```
const deleteItem = id => {
    let array = currentValues
    let index = array.findIndex(e => e.id === id)
    array.splice(index, 1)
    setCurrentValues(array)
}
```

The following problem occurs:

The deletion of the item in the array works, because when I do a console.log, I see the array is empty. The FlatList however does not re-render. When I click on an item to delete it, the username disappears (because it's deleted from the currentValues-item), but the item *itself* is not deleted, I still see a bordered rectangle.

When I just reset the array after I click one item, it works, so then the FlatList is re-rendered like it should. But then, all items are deleted at once (because I clear the array), and that's not what I want.

I tried the `extraData` prop. I added this to my flatlist:

```
extraData={currentValues}
```

I want to make sure the FlatList re-renders when the currentValues-array is updated, but this also does not work.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

BTW, changing from FlatList to ScrollView works (with the exact same functions). So I think it's a FlatList issue.

**Solution**

The solution (based on MBach's answer):

```
const deleteItem = id => {
    let array = [...currentValues]
    let index = array.findIndex(e => e.id === id)
    array.splice(index, 1)
    setCurrentValues([...array])
}
```

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397803/how-to-re-render-flatlist

Comment: Really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to force clone your array with spread operator:

```
let array = [...currentValues]
```

Or you can connect `currentValues` to `useEffect()`

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to you:

- use **keyExtractor** in flatlist.
- OR **key** in renderItem for cacheing flatlist data.

**Note**: index is not use as **key**, if you are using data which updating with time(chat messages) as due to update in data, index will also update, it will create same issue in iOS case so always use some unique key.