# Updating SectionList/FlatList data in react-native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to add data to the beginning (like unshift) of the list without jumping screen view and to achieve exactly the same behavior as when you add data to the end of it?

**Update:**
I've found my issue in this discussion - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25239, so it seems that it is not resolved yet and there is no way to do it without tears.

Comment: refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397803/how-to-re-render-flatlist) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can append data to the flatlist data.Flatlist will update when state changes.

```
  <FlatList
     extraData={this.state}
     data={this.state.Data}
     renderItem={({ item, index }) => (<View></View>))}/>
```

Comment: The behavior is the same with `extraData` prop and without it. The problem is not in updating the list, but in jumping view when I attach data to the beginning of the list