# How to make FlatList re-rendering with updated data

Tags: react-native, rendering, state, react-native-flatlist, rerender

I am building a kind of list component. in that component I am allowing user to make some changes in the flat list. I am trying to add the option of that if user pull to refresh to return back the main data was rendered before his modification 
Need Help to get that solved

```
     const [text, setText] = useState({});
        const [switchValue, setSwitchValue ] = useState(false);
        const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);


    const _handleOnPress = ({index}) => {
            const contentCopy = text.content;
            const current = contentCopy[index];
            const updatedContent = [...contentCopy.slice(0, index),
            {...current, repeat: current.repeat - 1}, ...contentCopy.slice(index + 1)];

            setText({...text, content:updatedContent});

        };

    const onRefresh = () => {}

      return (
             <View>

            <FlatList 
            data = {text.content}
            keyExtractor = {(text) => text.id}
            style = {styles.flatList}
            refreshing = {refresh}
            onRefresh = {onRefresh}
            extraData = {text.content}
            renderItem = {({item, index}) => {
                {if( item.repeat === 0 ) {
                    return null
                }
                return (
                    <View style = {styles.listContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => _handleOnPress({item, index})}>
                        <Amiri text = {item.text} />
                        <Spacer />
                        <PlaySound  link = {item.audio_url} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style = {styles.repeatContianer} >
                        <Spacer>
                            <Text style = {styles.repeatText}> {item.repeat} </Text>
                        </Spacer>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                );
            }

            }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with FlatList, you only need to update the data in the onRefresh function.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/43397803/11795209

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset the data then you will need to have 2 sets of data source.

1. original
2. updated

Use the "updated" data as your main data source
So when you use `onRefresh` you just need to set the "updated" data with data in "original"

```js
const [originalText] = React.useState({});
const [text, setText[ = React.useState({});
```

```js
onRefresh = () => {
   setText(originalText)
}
```

something along that way

ps: please edit your question because it's not related with the flat list, more about your state management

Comment: can you please clarify it more. I think I didn't get you.... I did the same but when refresh it shows empty list. can you please advice with other props like extraData and so on how would it be ?

Answer (score 0):

That what I found and worked well ...

first : add a state and let's call it refrshing and set it to false

```
const [refreshing, setRefreshing ] = useState(false);
```

second : in flat list add two props

```
refreshing = {refreshing} // same state //
onRefresh = {onRefresh} // function to be called back //
```

third : the function

```
const onRefresh = () => {
setRefresh(true);
Api () // get request again of data // 
}
```

fourth : in Api function itself

```
const Api = async() => {
        const response = await myApi.get(`/${id}`);
        setText(response.data);

        setRefreshing(false);

    };
```