# Re render React Native Flatlist on data fetch from API

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a React Native app where i'm using `Flatlist`.I have a list to render.But i want to add items to the list which i'm getting from the API on button click. I can see my API data on the console but they are not rendering for some reason. Also the list page i'm talking about is a child component. Here's what it looks like:

```js
class ProductList extends Component {
 state = {
                isSpinner: false,
  newArr: []
         };
  
   onScrollEndDrag = async() => {
  this.setState({ isSpinner: true });
  return await fetch(
   `myAPI`
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
   this.setState({ newArr: [...this.state.newArr, ...(json || [])] })
   return json;
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  this.setState({ isSpinner: false });
 } 
  
    render(){
     const list = [data1,data2,data3];
    return(
      <Fragment>
       <FlatList
 key={this.key}
 data={[...list,...this.state.newArr]}
 renderItem={this.renderItem}
 />
        <Button 
          title='Load More' 
          onPress={this.onScrollEndDrag}>
        </Button>
      </Fragment>
        )
      }
  }
```

What can be done to show the new API data with the existing list?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397803/how-to-re-render-flatlist) solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are anyways using `async await` no need of again using `.then` and `.catch` instead you can do it the below way.

```js
onScrollEndDrag = async() => {
    this.setState({ isSpinner: true });
    try {   
        const response = await fetch(`myAPI`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ 
          newArr: [...this.state.newArr, ...(json || [])], 
          isSpinner: false 
        }) 
    } catch(error) { 
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ isSpinner: false });
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yaah.It works. Thanks man. I have added extraData={this.state}  too. So, not really sure why it;s working.

Comment: As per the [FlatList docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html), By passing `extraData={state}` to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state changes. So my answer has simplified updating state after receiving response and providing `extraData` props is helping re-render.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks.