# How to update component style after changing the state in react native

Tags: react-native, setstate

I am trying to update the style of items in a flatlist based on a state that is kept in an array. After updating the state, the styles are not reflected although I see in the console that the flags have changed. Here are fragments of my code...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categoryState: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]. // states
    }
  }
```

//component being rendered

```
showCategories = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Ripple
        rippleDuration={1000}
        style={[styles.itemContainer, [this.state.categoryState[item.cIndex] !== 0 ? styles.selected : styles.notSelected]]}
        onPress={() => this.updateCategorieStatus(item)}
      >
       <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
      </Ripple>
    );
```

// function based on which I am changing the state and trying to update the style

```
updateCategorieStatus = (item) => {

    //changing selected state on the UI and updating the category state
 
   if (this.state.categoryState[item.cIndex] > 0) {

      let categoryState = this.state.categoryState
      categoryState[item.cIndex] = 0
      this.setState({ categoryState: categoryState });
      //console.log(this.state.categoryState);
    }
    else {
      let categoryState = this.state.categoryState
      categoryState[item.cIndex] = 1
      this.setState({ categoryState: categoryState });
      //console.log(this.state.categoryState);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to re-render flatlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397803/how-to-re-render-flatlist)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the square brackets in the `ternary operation` in the style logic, see the modified code here

```
<Ripple
    rippleDuration={1000}
    style={[styles.itemContainer, this.state.categoryState[item.cIndex] !== 0 ? styles.selected : styles.notSelected]}
    onPress={() => this.updateCategorieStatus(item)}
  >
```

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestion above, the problem was solved by updating the array in the function as follows:

```
updateCategorieStatus = (item) => {
    //changing selected state on the UI and updating the category state
    if (this.state.categoryState[item.cIndex] > 0) {
      let categoryState = [... this.state.categoryState]; // <=== changes
      categoryState[item.cIndex] = 0;
      this.setState({ categoryState });
      //console.log(this.state.categoryState);

    }
    else {
      let categoryState = [... this.state.categoryState];
      categoryState[item.cIndex] = 1;
      this.setState({ categoryState });
      //console.log(this.state.categoryState);
    }
  };
```