# Trouble re-rendering flatlist in functional component using extraData

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm struggling to re-render a flatlist. I'm trying to use a boolean `refreshToggle`, that is fed into `extraData`, that is changed after the desired information is successfully fetched. The code below successfully fetches the data and changes the boolean (so changing to functional updates for the state, while perhaps better practice, doesn't seem like a solution) (I've checked that this is happening with various logs etc), but the flatlist doesn't re-render.

```
export default function transactions({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {
    const [paymentsBtnActive, setPaymentsBtnActive] = React.useState<boolean>(navigation.getParam('Pressed') == 'Payments');
    const [requestsBtnActive, setRequestsBtnActive] = React.useState<boolean>(navigation.getParam('Pressed') == 'Requests');
    const [refreshToggle, setRefreshToggle] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    let data: any[] = [];

    async function getRequests() {
        const body = { 
            'phone': GLOBAL.userInfo['phone']
        }
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }
        let requests =  await fetch('http://3ef68e9c1352.ngrok.io/requests/user', options);
        let requestsJSON = await requests.json();
        data = requestsJSON['data'];
    }    

    function renderItem(item: any) {
        return (<Text>{item['item']['data']['date']}</Text>)
    }
    
    function listEmpty(){
        return (<Text>Loading</Text>)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function () {
            await getRequests();
            setRefreshToggle(!refreshToggle)
        })()
    }, [])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
            <View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style = { paymentsBtnActive ? styles.paymentsBtnActive : styles.paymentsBtnInactive } onPress = { () => { setRequestsBtnActive(paymentsBtnActive) 
                    setPaymentsBtnActive(!paymentsBtnActive) } } >
                    <Text style = { paymentsBtnActive ? styles.whiteText : styles.redText }>Payments</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style = { requestsBtnActive ? styles.requestsBtnActive : styles.requestsBtnInactive } onPress = { () => { setPaymentsBtnActive(requestsBtnActive)
                    setRequestsBtnActive(!requestsBtnActive) } }  >
                    <Text style = { requestsBtnActive ? styles.whiteText : styles.redText }>Requests</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>


            <View style = {styles.summaryView}>
                <FlatList 
                    data={data} 
                    renderItem={renderItem} 
                    ListEmptyComponent = {listEmpty}
                    extraData = {refreshToggle}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
export default function transactions({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) {
    const [paymentsBtnActive, setPaymentsBtnActive] = React.useState<boolean>(navigation.getParam('Pressed') == 'Payments');
    const [requestsBtnActive, setRequestsBtnActive] = React.useState<boolean>(navigation.getParam('Pressed') == 'Requests');
    const [data, setData] = React.useState<Array<any>>([]);

    async function getRequests() {
        const body = { 
            'phone': GLOBAL.userInfo['phone']
        }
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }
        let requests =  await fetch('http://3ef68e9c1976.ngrok.io/requests/user', options);
        let requestsJSON = await requests.json();
        setData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(requestsJSON['data'])))
    }    

    function renderItem(item: any) {
        console.log(item)
        return (<Text>{item['item']['data']['date']}</Text>)
    }
    
    function listEmpty(){
        return (<Text>Loading</Text>)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function () {
            await getRequests();
        })()
    }, [])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
            <View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style = { paymentsBtnActive ? styles.paymentsBtnActive : styles.paymentsBtnInactive } onPress = { () => { setRequestsBtnActive(paymentsBtnActive) 
                    setPaymentsBtnActive(!paymentsBtnActive) } } >
                    <Text style = { paymentsBtnActive ? styles.whiteText : styles.redText }>Payments</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style = { requestsBtnActive ? styles.requestsBtnActive : styles.requestsBtnInactive } onPress = { () => { setPaymentsBtnActive(requestsBtnActive)
                    setRequestsBtnActive(!requestsBtnActive) } }  >
                    <Text style = { requestsBtnActive ? styles.whiteText : styles.redText }>Requests</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>


            <View style = {styles.summaryView}>
                <FlatList 
                    data={data} 
                    renderItem={renderItem} 
                    ListEmptyComponent = {listEmpty}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

This way when `getRequests` is called a new array with a difference reference is assigned to `data` so the Flatlist is re-rendered.

Because the all of the data was changing, this was not a scenario in which using `extraData` was necessary, nor the kind of scenario for which `extraData` was designed. Nonetheless, my initial approach was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49505891/4811743), and I am still not sure why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this instead

```js
let [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);

const getRequests = useCallback(async function() {
   const body = {'phone': GLOBAL.userInfo['phone']}
   
   const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
   }

   let requests =  await fetch('http://3ef68e9c1352.ngrok.io/requests/user', 
   options);

   let requestsJSON = await requests.json();

   return requestsJSON['data']
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  (async function () {
     const data = await getRequests();
     setData(data)
   })()
}, [])


<FlatList 
   data={data}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   ListEmptyComponent = {listEmpty}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see why this would work, it is very similar to how I solved the problem. If I understand correctly, both work in essence because data is updated with a new array with a different reference when `getRequests` is called. I'm still not sure why I couldn't get the `extraData` approach to work (although I now understand that, because the all of the data was changing, this was not really a scenario in which using `extraData` was necessary, nor the kind of scenario for which `extraData` was intended)